# Several graphs in 1 loop, each iteration adds a line on every figure

Tags: matlab, plot, legend, figure, axes

Trying to engineer the following in Matlab:

```
** loop start;
   y(:,i) = function of x;
   z(:,i) = function of x;
   plot(x,y(:,i))   on figure 1, hold all;
   plot(x,z(:,i))   on figure 2, hold all;
** loop end;
   add title, legend, etc for figure 1 (NB: we have multiple lines);
   add title, legend, ets for figure 2 (NB: same, have multiple lines for the legend);`
```

Tried multiple combinations without much luck. Managed to get 2 figures but only the 2-nd displays multiple lines, not the first. And can't figure how to add legends to these 2 correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save a handle to each figure, and to each axis object:

```
fh1 = figure;
hold all;
ah1 = gca;

fh2 = figure;
hold all;
ah2 = gca;

for i=1:N
    y(:,i) = function of x;
    z(:,i) = function of x;
    plot(ah1, x, y(:,i)); %# tell it which axis to use (ah1)
    plot(ah2, x, z(:,i)); %# (ah2)
end

legend(ah1, ...) %# legend options here
legend(ah2, ...) %# and the other legend

%# note: you can set figure properties for each using fh1, fh2 handles.
```

Comment: Works great. If you have a chance to answer -- why is it ok to put "hold all" in front of the loop? I did handles too, apparently 2-nd "hold all" was missing or in a wrong place.

Comment: "hold all" works on the current axes.  If an axes object doesn't exist, it creates one.  That's why it works before you plot anything.

Comment: How should one do "hold off"'s? Something like 
figure(1);
hold off;
figure(2);
hold off;

Comment: From the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/hold.html): `hold off` resets hold state to the default behavior, in which MATLAB clears the existing graph and resets axes properties to their defaults before drawing new plots.

Comment: Well, not like I would want to get rid of all of my lines but theoretically once I have 'hold on' activated on both figures I "need" (or might want) to deactivate it on both too. I don't see how to use 'ah1' and 'ah2' to implement such de-activations => hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
figHandle1 = figure(1);
figHandle2 = figure(2);
```

Then when you want to plot on that figure do this:

```
figure(figHandle1) %Plot on figure 1
%ie plot(someStuff)
figure(figHandle2) %Plot on figure 2
```

Also its the same for the title and stuff, you jjust need to identify which figure by doing:

```
figure(handle);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `figure(h)` will bring the handle `h` to the front, so new things are put into the figure - so, this will work.  However, it is comparatively slower than just specifying which handle to use by giving the handle to the plot command (i.e. what I did in my answer).  This can be important if you'd be switching figures often (as the OP would be doing, twice each time in a loop).

Comment: @tmpearce I didn't know that, but thanks, hopefully the OP isnt running that many loops.

Comment: I tried this before and tried again just now. The result -- 1 line on figure 1 and 10 lines on figure 2. I am reluctant to put all the code here as functions are very sophisticated. But everything works if I 'kill' figure 2 & ask to plot only figure 1, then all 10 lines are there.

Comment: Actually I just found the bug: there should be "hold all" used twice after every plot inside the loop.